# Cloning from Microsoft Azure to local git repository

Tags: python, django, git, azure

I apologize if this is such a newbie question, but I am new to Git and source control in general. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

I created a Django web application on Microsoft Azure (following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/) tutorial), created a local repository on my computer (following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) tutorial), and tried to clone the python files from Azure to my local repository, but I always end up copying the contents of my local repo into itself instead.

These were the commands I used, in this order:

```
cd <local_repository>
git init
git add README.txt
git commit -m "Adding README.txt to the repository"
git remote add azure <git_url_azure>
git push azure master
git clone <git_url_azure>
```

I need to clone the contents of my Django application into my local repository so I can open the Visual Studio solution from there and get coding. The solution must be pretty simple but I can't find answers on the internet. What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to clone here. You created the files locally and pushed them to the server; there's no need to "clone back" from the server to the master.

Comment: I created a Django application through the Microsoft Azure portal. Following the linked tutorials to the letter, I was trying to get the python files generated by me creating that Django app and putting them into my local repository. I may have used the wrong Git commands to accomplish that.

Comment: But the first tutorial didn't say anything about creating a local repo and pushing that. You should just clone the one on the server. The only command you need out of all the ones you show here is the last one.

Comment: The first tutorial linked me to the second one, which said to create a local repo. Does that mean that as soon as I initialize the local repo, I should immediately just use the last command?

Comment: No, you do not even initialize a local repo. That is what cloning does. *Only* use the last command.

Comment: I knew the solution was going to be embarrassingly simple. Sorry about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use only git clone repository command. What you are trying to do is not the cloning, but instead of that a whole bunch of different actions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clone the repository (Each repository can be used as a source). For example:

```
git clone <git_url_azure> my_dir
```

You may need to change the `origin` remote branch afterwards.

However, you may also need to create a clone in which you can push from other directories (Like a backup). In this case you need to create a "bare" directory, ie a directory that contains only the database but is not populated:

```
git clone --bare my_dir
```

This will permit creating a clone based on it:

```
git clone my_dir my_new_dir
cd my_new_dir
... (Some modifications, commits, branches...)
git push origin
```